# SQL query group by and having all

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, self-join

I have a table:

```
Parent Child Educated
'P1', 'C1', 'YES'
'P1', 'C2', 'YES'
'P1', 'C3', 'NO'
'P2', 'C11', 'YES'
'P2', 'C12', 'NO'
'P3', 'C21', 'YES'
'P3', 'C22', 'YES'
'P4', 'C31', 'NO'
'P4', 'C32', 'NO'
```

Now, I need to find all the parents who have all their children educated, i.e, Educated='YES'.

Like in above case parent 'P3'

Can anyone suggest a query to fetch this

Comment: Find those that don't have any children educated = 'no'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select parent
from t
group by parent
having max(educated) = min(educated) and max(educated) = 'YES';
```

The logic is slightly more complicated if `educated` could be `NULL`.

Actually, if the value is just `'YES'` or `'NO'`, you can do the simpler:

```
select parent
from t
group by parent
having min(educated) = 'YES';
```

Comment: the second part of the answer threw me off. It is not just a shortcut, but another case, beware!

Answer (score 5):

```
select parent, 
       sum(case when educated='YES' then 1 else 0 end) as sum_educated,
       count(*) as count_all
from t
group by parent
having count_all=sum_educated
```

Comment: In MySQL you don't actually need the CASE.

Answer (score 1):

Finding Parents that have any record with 'No' and using `NOT IN` to remove those from the result:

```
SELECT parent
FROM table
WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM table WHERE Educated = 'No')
GROUP BY parent
```

Comment: Didn't your mum ever tell you "Do not use `IN` for lists any longer than what you'd be prepared to write by hand"? :)

Answer (score -3):

select * from [YourTable]
where Educated = 'Yes'

If you only want Parent column to be displayed 
then select Parent from [YourTable]
where Educated = 'Yes'

Comment: *where ALL children for the parent are "Yes"